# How to wait for function to complete before returning?

Tags: intern, leadfoot

i'm attempting to create a function I can call from any test that'll look at the element being passed (link text, Css Selector, Xpath, ID), click on the element, and then verify the URL that comes up after it loads.  The problem i'm having is that it's returning before the function is finished.

I know I need to implement async and a callback, but i'm having a hard time understanding the structure.

```
clickIDverifyURL: function clickByID (elementVar, elementURL){
        var rem = this.remote;

        // if statements to look at elementVar and select the right one.. example:
        // rem.setFindByTimeout(10000)
        // .findByXpath (elementVar)
        // .click()
        // .end()

        return this.remote
            // if I code it right, I shouldn't need this sleep right?
            .sleep(30000)
            .getCurrentUrl()
            .then(function(currURL) {
                console.log(currURL);
                try {
                    assert.strictEqual(currURL, elementURL, "This test checks to see if the current URL is correct.")
                }
                catch (e)
                {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });

    }
```

Appreciate any help or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Assuming you want to click the element, wait for a page transition, then check the resulting URL, you could do something like:

```
clickIDverifyURL: function (elementURL) {
    return function (element) {
        return this.parent
            .then(function () {
                return element.click();
            })

            // Wait for the page transition. This can be a sleep, or you can search for an
            // element that should be on the new page (intern will implicitly wait for it
            // to appear), or use pollUntil to wait for a more specific condition.
            .sleep(1000)

            // Get the page URL
            .getCurrentUrl()
            .then(function (url) {
                assert.strictEqual(url, elementURL);
            });
    }
}
```

You would use it like:

```
.findElementByCssSelector('.someselector')
.then(myModule.clickIDverifyURL('expectedURL'))
```

`clickIDVerifyURL` takes in some configuration data (the expected URL) and returns a function that can be called in a Command's `then` callback. Such functions have a `parent` property in their context that references the parent Command chain (the chain of functions started from `this.remote`).

Note that methods called on Elements, like `element.click()` above, return Promises, not Commands. This means that only standard Promise methods can be chained, not Command methods like `click`, `findElementByX`, etc. That's why the code above starts the inner chain from `this.parent` rather than `element`.

**Update**

The same basic structure works for other types of helper method. For example, if you wanted to use a helper method to do a find, it might look like:

```
findBySomething: function (selector) {
    return function () {
        var setContext = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
        return this.parent
            .findByCssSelector(selector)
            .then(function (element) {
                setContext(element);
            });
    }
}
```

Then you could do

```
this.remote
    .then(myModule.findBySomething('.selector'))
    .then(myModule.clickIDverifyURL('expected URL'))
```

Comment: Thanks jason0x43.  I've got a better idea of how to structure it now.  Would it make sense to create a separate method for the type of element?  I want to be able to use regex to break down the first characters so that developers can just hand off to us a few various elements (either css selector, xpath, or div id).  Would it go:

`myModule.findElement('.someselector')
.then(myModule.clickIDverifyURL('expectedURL'))`

if so, what should findElement be return to maintain the chain?

Comment: For that, you could do something like...um, a comment isn't great for this. I'll update the answer...